# How can I generate UUID in c++, without using boost library?

Tags: c++, uuid

I want to generate UUID for my application to distinguish each installation of my application. I want to generate this UUID using C++ without boost library support. How can I generate UUID using some other opensource library?

Note: My platform is windows

Comment: [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

Comment: On windows you can use `UuidCreate` its in `rpc.h`. For example: http://nogeekhere.blogspot.in/2008/07/how-to-generate-uuid-guid-in-c.html

Comment: plus one for "without using boost"

Answer (score 28):

This will do, if you're using modern C++.

```
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

namespace uuid {
    static std::random_device              rd;
    static std::mt19937                    gen(rd());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 15);
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis2(8, 11);

    std::string generate_uuid_v4() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        int i;
        ss << std::hex;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-4";
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        ss << dis2(gen);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        };
        return ss.str();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting, this output is formatted like a guid, but isn't "unique enough" to be a guid.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/
std::mt19937 has 32 bits of randomness, or 4E9 combinations. A true guid has 128 bits of randomness, or 3E38 combinations. A true guid would be a (bil bil bil)x more random.
mt19937->mt19937_64 would be an improvement, which is 64 bits of randomness, or 1.8E19 combinations, but still wouldn't be a guid, in terms of the randomness expectation.

Comment: one question: 32 bits of randomness + 32 bits of randomnes + .... + 32 bits of randomness is not equal to 128 bits of randomness???

Comment: @RaulLuna No, as this is pseudo-random number generator, so all subsequent invocations depend on previous. Like making SHA256 from int16 will still produce 65 thousands of unique hashes, not 2**256. std::mt19937 contains more bits of state inside, but that depends on initial state, so very unclear subsequences. Real UUIDs are much more reliable in terms of uniqueness.

Comment: the PRNG has a large enough state (19937 bits) but it is being seeded entirely by a 32-bit value generated by the random_device (`rd()`) so this function can only ever generate 2^32 possible uuids. downvoted, **do NOT use this** or any similar answer or you could introduce a security issue, see [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device)

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [UuidCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")  // UuidCreate - Minimum supported OS Win 2000
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UUID uuid;
    UuidCreate(&uuid);
    char *str;
    UuidToStringA(&uuid, (RPC_CSTR*)&str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #Yuval, should I download rpcrt4.lib and keep that library files in lib folder?, or else rpcrt4.lib is available in windows. sorry to ask such silly question

Comment: @PURE this library is included with the installation of Visual Studio

Comment: Or use CoCreateGuid which is a wrapper around UuidCreate.

Comment: Note than in order to link rpcrt4.lib, you must open your project's properties, go to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line, and then type Rpcrt4.lib into the Additional Options box.

Comment: `#include <rpc.h>` was necessary for me (instead of `#include <windows.h>`)

Answer (score 14):

If you just want something random, I wrote this small function:

```
string get_uuid() {
    static random_device dev;
    static mt19937 rng(dev());

    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 15);

    const char *v = "0123456789abcdef";
    const bool dash[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    string res;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (dash[i]) res += "-";
        res += v[dist(rng)];
        res += v[dist(rng)];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Nina No guarantee, but you are more likely to get struck by lightning after wining the lottery than have a collision.

Comment: thanks @CaptainCodeman. Quite ready to be used with std lib. Perfect.

Answer (score 7):

The [ossp-uuid](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) library can generate UUIDs and has C++ bindings.

It seems extremely simple to use:

```
#include <uuid++.hh>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        uuid id;
        id.make(UUID_MAKE_V1);
        const char* myId = id.string();
        cout << myId << endl;
        delete myId;
}
```

Note that it allocates and returns a C-style string, which the calling code must deallocate to avoid a leak.

Another possibility is libuuid, which is part of the util-linux package, available from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/. Any Linux machine will have it installed already. It does not have a C++ API but is still callable from C++ using the C API.

Comment: A word of caution about calling uuid's string() function, this allocates memory that must be deallocated by the calling code!  In the above answer, calling id.string() returns a char* to newly allocated memory, not a nice std::string (which manages its memory via destructor/RAII).

So the above code has a memory leak.  It would be better to set char* str = id.string() and then call delete on str once finished using it.

Comment: @jCuga good grief, I didn't even notice that! Thanks, have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

In 2021, I suggest to use the single-header library [stduuid](https://github.com/mariusbancila/stduuid). It's cross-platform and it does not bring in any unwanted dependencies.

Download `uuid.h` from the project's github page, then a minimal working example is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define UUID_SYSTEM_GENERATOR
#include "uuid.h"

int main (void) {
    std::string id = uuids::to_string (uuids::uuid_system_generator{}());
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
}
```

See the project's github page for more details and documentation on various options and generators.

Comment: does this repo get test well?

Comment: This library appears to use the std::mt19937 so I think it still fails the "unique enough" issue already discussed on this question.

Comment: This lib is an implementation of a proposal to be added to the stdlib, so has a  very thorough API. It needs C++17

Comment: API might be clean and the reason why it’s proposed, but this has nothing to do with the implementation

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally UUID's are simply the machine's MAC address concatenated with with the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the adoption of the Gregorian calendar in the West.  So it's not too difficult to write a C++ `class` that does this for you.

Comment: But I need to generate UUID (type 4) based on random numbers, #Paul. I coudn't use normal rand() function available in C++. Thant is why I trying for library files.

Comment: There's several [versions and variants of UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Variants_and_versions); your answer only covers Version 1.

Comment: @user3732956: Why can't you use `rand()` or any other (pseudo-) random function, if what you are trying to do *is* a random UUID?

Comment: ya, to go pseudo random function, I think I should go to library files, right. that is why I prefer directly UUID library files.

Comment: This style of UUID (type 1) has been abandoned in favour of UUIDs that don't leak PII.

Comment: C++11 has `<random>`, much better than `rand()`

Answer (score 1):

The Linux utility libuuid has you covered. Here is an example to fill a UUID ROS message. Any other buffer of 16 bytes will do, too. The usage is very straightforward:

```
#include "uuid/uuid.h"

...

unique_identifier_msgs::msg::UUID uuid;
uuid_generate(uuid.uuid.data());
```

The same API is available on the Mac as well. This cmake code shows what to link where https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/CMake/FindUUID.cmake

Other solutions to this question explain how to use the windows native API in case one needs to cover all three platforms.

**docs**

```
man 3 uuid_generate
```

or online
https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/libuuid/man/uuid_generate.3.adoc

**License**

Permissive, see header  of https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/libuuid/src/uuid.h

**why this new answer**

Expanding on the answer by @harmic because it mentions two solutions, and the latter is easily lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rst](https://github.com/sabbakumov/rst/blob/master/rst/guid/guid.h#L57) C++ library that I developed to do that:

```
#include "rst/guid/guid.h"

std::string guid = rst::Guid().AsString();

// Performs no allocations.
std::cout << rst::Guid().AsStringView().value() << std::endl;
```

Comment: The GitHub project you've linked appears to be your own. If this *is* the case, then you **must explicitly disclose** that fact, or your post may be considered as spam.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :).

```
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib") 
#include <windows.h>
#include <rpcdce.h>
/*
* Generate a Universal Unique Identifier using windows api.
* Note: throw exceptions if uuid wasn't created successfully.
*/
std::string generate_uuid()
{
    UUID uuid;
    RPC_CSTR  uuid_str;
    std::string uuid_out;

    if (UuidCreate(&uuid) != RPC_S_OK)
        std::cout << "couldn't create uuid\nError code" << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    if (UuidToStringA(&uuid, &uuid_str) != RPC_S_OK)
        std::cout << "couldn't convert uuid to string\nError code" << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    uuid_out = (char*)uuid_str;
    RpcStringFreeA(&uuid_str);
    return uuid_out;
}
```