# How to generate a unique string for each device in c++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

The goal is to generate a unique string for each device running (linux, windows, macos) which can not be altered and does not change if user upgrades components of the device other than motherboard

While doing research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365331/how-can-i-generate-uuid-in-c-without-using-boost-library) question that has some interesting answers one of them is this

```
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

namespace uuid {
    static std::random_device              rd;
    static std::mt19937                    gen(rd());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 15);
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis2(8, 11);

    std::string generate_uuid_v4() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        int i;
        ss << std::hex;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-4";
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        ss << dis2(gen);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        }
        ss << "-";
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            ss << dis(gen);
        };
        return ss.str();
    }
}
```

on windows this generates a string that does not change but on linux (ubuntu) this generates a new string everytime you run the compiled file which is not what I am looking for

I found this command for linux systems that find the HWID for linux but it requires admin privileges and it can be changed

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

Comment: "not be altered and does not change if user upgrades components of the device other than motherboard" - consider virtual-machines, emulation, and programmable baseband/baseboard controllers.

Comment: @Dai can you elaborate

Comment: _"...on windows this generates a string that does not change..."_ using MSVC or MinGW? If MinGW this is due to a known bug (not fixed IIRC).

Comment: @RichardCritten using MinGW

Comment: @ahmad see [Bug 85494 - implementation of random_device on mingw is useless](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85494) That's why with MinGW you the same string every run